# How to identify field with id in Appium using CodeceptJS?

Tags: android, xpath, appium, appium-android, codeceptjs

I am trying to use CodeceptJS (which uses Appium) to test a native Android app. I want use the method I.seeElement to see that a field is present, but the Appium server just seems to hang with no error message.

This step is to input a phone number so the user can log in.I have been able to click on a button prior to this but that's because I was able to use a simple text identifier.

Here is what I've written. (The I.click method works when it clicks a button.)

```
// in this file you can append custom step methods to 'I' object

module.exports = function() {
  return actor({

    login: function (I) {
        I.click('ALLOW');
        I.seeElement('#com.[package name removed]:id/phone');
    }

  });
}
```

This is the error message:

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/5e57e7af-ca1c-46bf-94ac-7e2f113a26fa/elements
[HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//*[@resource-id='com.[package name removed]:id/phone']"}
[debug] [W3C (5e57e7af)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["xpath","//*[@resource-id='com.[package name removed]:id/phone']","5e57e7af-ca1c-46bf-94ac-7e2f113a26fa"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[@resource-id='com.[package name removed]:id/phone']","context":"","multiple":true}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[@resource-id='com.[package name removed]:id/phone']","context":"","multiple":true}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//*[@resource-id='com.[package name removed]:id/phone']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use smart selector like by some dynamic id example :

```
'div[id$="test"] textarea'    //ends with id test
'[id^='test']'      //start with id test
```

also you can use smart locators see codeceptjs locators

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, but this looks like code for testing a website and I'm testing a native Android app. I think it wasn't explicit in my original question, so I'm going to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the text for the element you have to see. I.seeElement("~TEXT OF THE ELEMENT")

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's a field. I realize I should have specified this in the question and have updated it. If I understand correctly, for a field there's no text.